# Descomprimir archivo .zip en r

Tags: r, descarga

He descargado la Encuesta de Gasto Turístico del Instituto Canario de Estadística (ISTAC). Pero no logro descomprimir el archivo que me he descargado con un script de R. He intentado lo siguiente:

```
url <- 'http://www.gobiernodecanarias.org/istac/galerias/documentos/C00028A/egt-metodologia-2018-microdatos-2020q3.html'
EGTcomp<-download.file(url = url, destfile = 'EGT.zip')
```

Para descomprimirlo:

```
unzip(zipfile = EGTcomp)
```

Que me devuelve lo siguiente:

> Error in unzip(zipfile = EGTcomp) : invalid zip name argument

También he probado

```
unzip(zipfile = 'EGT.zip')
```

Que me devuelve

> In unzip(zipfile = "EGT.zip") : internal error in 'unz' code

**¿Cómo puedo descomprimir el archivo?**

Comment: La invocación correcta es la segunda `unzip(zipfile = 'EGT.zip')`, prueba hacer en primer lugar la descarga en modo binario, es decir `download.file(url = url, destfile = 'EGT.zip', mode='wb')` y avisame si funcionó. Saludos.

Comment: No entiendo por qué, pero funcionó :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Buceando un poco en la ayuda de `download.file()` extraigo estos comentarios que explican esta particularidad:

> The choice of binary transfer (mode = "wb" or "ab") is important on
> Windows, since unlike Unix-alikes it does distinguish between text and
> binary files and for text transfers changes \n line endings to \r\n
> (aka ‘CRLF’).
>
> On Windows, if mode is not supplied (missing()) and url ends in one of
> .gz, .bz2, .xz, .tgz, .zip, .rda, .rds or .RData, mode = "wb" is set
> such that a binary transfer is done to help unwary users.
>
> Code written to download binary files must use mode = "wb" (or "ab"),
> but the problems incurred by a text transfer will only be seen on
> Windows.

Es decir:

- En Windows se distingue entre un modo de descarga "Texto" o "Binario", esto por que en modo "Texto" y en este SO en particular, se modifican los caracteres de salto de línea en la descarga: `\r -> \r\n`.
- Si no se establece este modo, de forma automática se define el modo binario únicamente para ciertas extensiones de archivos, la lista es clara, archivos comprimidos y objetos de R.
- En tu caso, la descarga parte de un HTML básicamente un archivo de texto, por lo que el modo de descarga usado será "Texto", y por consiguiente, la descarga modificará ciertos "bytes" del archivo, cosa que "rompe" finalmente el zip.
- En mi opinión, en Windows, siempre deberíamos (o al menos casi siempre) usar el modo binario mediante:

  ```
  download.file(url = url, destfile = 'EGT.zip', mode='wb')
  ```